# will usage of craco cause JavaScript heap out of memory error

Tags: reactjs, deployment, gitlab, craco

```
FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0xa2b020 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x97a467 node::FatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0xb9e0ee v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0xb9e467 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0xd3e875  [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0xd3f21b v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0xd4d012 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0xd4de65 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0xd5082c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0xd1fecb v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x1050340 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInOldGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x13a9ed9  [/usr/local/bin/node]
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables
00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

got this error when deploying the branch in gitlab. changes made before the deployment were ( in package.json )

```
 `  "scripts": {
"start": "craco start",
"build": "craco build",
"test": "craco test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"format": "prettier --write src/**/*.ts{,x}",
"lint": "tsc --noEmit && eslint src/**/*.ts{,x}"
```

},`

am new to craco. I have used craco to customize the antd theme and followed the guidelines mention in their documentation. later on, I went through the usage of craco but still, I don't have complete knowledge in craco. I need some explanation why it has not given an error without craco and it's giving an error when using craco. so does this mean craco will consume more memory than using `react-script start`

Comment: fixed this error by modifying the script like this 

`"start": "craco --max_old_space_size=4096 start",`
`"build": "craco --max_old_space_size=4096 build",`
 
can someone explain what is actually happening and what is the real usage of craco
Thanks in advance